# Displacement vector in terms of a position vector and velocity

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it correct to say that, given $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$, a point on a curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be given by $$\gamma(t)=\gamma(t_0)+(t-t_0)\dot{\gamma}(t)$$ for all $t>t_0$? I'm guessing not since the velocity is not assumed constant...so is there a way of expressing any point on a curve given a fixed point on a curve and its velocity?

Comment: hey yeah, I'm really sorry I was getting mixed up between maths and physics stack exchange. Thank you very much for your help; I certainly agree with what you've said and it's help - i"ll upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about
$$
\gamma(t)=\gamma(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t \dot\gamma(\tau)\mathrm d\tau
\;?$$